# Angular 2 and rxjs: How to have a dynamic array property in a child component that is a filtered subset of a parent's property?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I'm experimenting with Angular 2 and its new reactive concepts.

Let's say right now I have a BookStore, which contains a list of all books in the store (fetched from an external API/source). In that store you find a couple of shelves, which respectively contain a subset of the available books.

So using classes you'd end up with something like this:

```
export class BookStore {
    public books: Book[]
}

export class Shelf {
    public shelfId: string
    public store: BookStore
    public shelfBooks: /* ????, Observable? */

    /* here I'd like to have something declarative that allows me to filter the books that have their shelfId == a shelf's ID. */

   constructor() {
       this.shelfBooks = /* ... (self.store.books) */
           .filter( book => book.shelfId == this.shelfId )
           /* Have this dynamically updating the property if the parent's book list changes - how? */
   } 
}
```

In a template I'd like to use the ngFor directive to reflect the list of books in each shelf view.

What is the "official" approach to this?

I've read about Observables, but those seem to be mostly used for Http and other things. Angular 2 already has a very good change detection system, but I'm not sure what approach to use here.

Comment: Yes, considering that `self.store.books` is an observable that gets new values, `this.shelfBooks` observable will be dynamically updated. Do you have problems with this approach? Can you replicate it as a plunk if you do?

Comment: I think I have some kind of brain blocker here. I'd like shelfBooks to update automatically whenever the books in the BookStore change or update. Unfortunately I have no idea what to google for or where to find working examples. The documentation is pretty thin on this too.

Comment: I guess you can start with filling the gaps in the code you've posted. What is `self.store.books`? Is it an observable? Where is it assigned? How is `Shelf` being used?